# WSO2 API manager with Kubenetes deployed back end services

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am thinking of deploying the WSO2 API manager/GW in VM's (Not in kubernetes) and forwarding all API calls to a nginx ingress controller running in my kubernetes cluster which also has all the back end services that expose API's. I could not find any info on the documentation for deployment like this and wanted to check if this has any known pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable and acceptable. For API Manager gateways, your backend services look like just another endpoint. When you are creating an API in the API publisher you can create an API and provide the ingress URL for your backend service. If the gateway can access the ingress gateway, you should be able to invoke the API successfully. Only drawback in this approach is network latency.

If you deploy the API manager in K8s, then you can drop this network latency as you can access the backend services via the services in K8s. If you do not have any concern with the latency, you can follow this approach. I have seen this pattern in the industry and people are using this approach.

If you want to deploy API Manager in K8s, you can check https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim

Comment: Thanks. I saw the APIM kubenetes deployment pattern, but I was not sire if this was well production tested?

Comment: There are users who run these artifacts in production.